# How to include php file on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is that possible to output some php code, in JS, than includes a php template when clicked on a buton? I am trying the following way like below without success. How can i do it?

```js
$("#show").one('click', function () {
$("#showTemplate").html("<?php require_once 'php-template.php'; ?>") 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "showTemplate"> </div>
<button id="show"></button>
```

Comment: You can use ajax to get output from php , instead trying to include php code which is wrong.

Comment: try writing your js code inside php something like this.  <?php echo"
        <script>$('#show').one('click', function () {
$('#showTemplate').html('php-template.php') 
});</script> " ;?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax instead and since you want to output some php code then you'll have to set the `header` from your php template to `text/plain`.

```
$.ajax ({
     url: 'php-template.php',
     type: 'get',
     dataType: 'text',
     success: function (data){
         $('#showTemplate').html (data);
     });
 })
```

And in your php template, you'll need to set the header,

```
header ('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Comment: You rarely need to explicitly set that header since it's the default. You also usually don't need to set the `type: 'text'`, since jquery will recognize the response and use it properly.

Comment: Thanks. It was just a mistake I meant `dataType` instead of `type`. I just like to explicitly set the settings on my ajax requests though. Just my preferences, was hard coding here with mobile phone. XD